# Kmeans label not defined

Tags: python

I would appreciate it if someone can help as I'm new to machine learning itself. I'm working on KMeans; I want to identify how many data samples have been assigned to each cluster I have specified. The below is the code I have written so far, but on running this, I obtained the error
'kmeans_labels' is not defined

```
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
import numpy as np

kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=2, random_state=0).fit(X_train_norm)

# Identifying how many data samples have been assigned to each cluster
import numpy as np

unique_labels, unique_counts = np.unique(kmeans_labels, return_counts=True)
dict(zip(unique_labels, unique_counts))
```

Comment: I _think_ you wanted `unique_labels, unique_counts = np.unique(kmeans.labels_, return_counts=True)` - `labels_` is an attribute on the `KMeans` instance.

Comment: It works now. Thanks for helping to spot that.